# Result not stable for parallel merge sort in java, for the same input, sometimes it works, sometimes not

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

Here is the code.

I use parallel computing to build the merge sort and the MergeSortTask class creates multiple threads to divide the array into some sub-array and use merge sort to sort it. The MergeTask is the thread to merge two sorted arrays into one sorted array. For generating array is in the getArray function, and I add a seed on this generating part.
For the MergeSortTask part, I think there are not any bugs on it. So the problem is on the MergeTask part.
For the two input arrays a,b. I try to get the rank(a) and rank(b), of each element using binary search which means the position in arrays a and b if I put the element into that array. And the default data is Long.MIN_VALUE in the result array, and if

```
result[rank(a)+rank(b)].equal(Long.MIN_VALUE)
```

I may assign that element into that position, if not just use open addressing.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TotalParallelMergeSort {
    static Long[] arr;
    static Long[] checking;
    static int pnum = 10;

    static Long[] result;

    static int size=100000;

    static int beginning=0;

    static Queue<Long[]> que= new LinkedList<>();
    static Long[] a;
    static Long[] b;
    
    private static class MergeTask extends Thread {
        int[] Class;
        int[] rank;
        public MergeTask(int[] Class, int[] rank) {
            this.Class=Class;
            this.rank=rank;
        }

        public void run() {
            int lastFind = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Class.length; i++) {
                if (i > 0 && this.Class[i] == this.Class[i - 1] &&
                        ((this.Class[i] == 0 && a[rank[i]].equals(a[rank[i] - 1]) ) ||
                                (this.Class[i] == 1 && b[rank[i]].equals(b[rank[i] - 1])))) {
                    boolean tmp = true;
                    while (lastFind < result.length && tmp) {
                        synchronized (result[lastFind]) {
                            if (result[lastFind] != Long.MIN_VALUE) {lastFind++;}
                              else {
                                result[lastFind] = this.Class[i] == 0 ? a[rank[i]] : b[rank[i]];
                                tmp = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (this.Class[i] == 0) {
                    int left = 0;
                    int right = b.length - 1;
                    while (right > left) {
                        int mid = (right + left) / 2;
                        if (a[rank[i]] <= b[mid]) {
                            right = mid - 1;
                        } else if (a[rank[i]] > b[mid]) {
                            left = mid + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    while (left < b.length && a[rank[i]] > b[left]) left++;
                    boolean tmp = true;
                    while (tmp) {
                        synchronized (result[rank[i] + left]) {
                            if (result[rank[i] + left] != Long.MIN_VALUE) {
                                left++;
                            } else {
                                tmp = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    result[rank[i] + left] = a[rank[i]];
                    lastFind = rank[i] + left;
                }
                else if (this.Class[i] == 1) {
                    int left = 0;
                    int right = a.length - 1;
                    while (right > left) {
                        int mid = (right + left) / 2;
                        if (b[rank[i]] <= a[mid]) {
                            right = mid - 1;
                        } else if (b[rank[i]] > a[mid]) {
                            left = mid + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    while (left < a.length && b[rank[i]] > a[left]) left++;
                    boolean tmp = true;
                    while (tmp) {
                        synchronized (result[rank[i] + left]) {
                            if ( result[rank[i] + left] != Long.MIN_VALUE) {
                                left++;
                            } else {
                                tmp = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    result[rank[i] + left] = b[rank[i]];
                    lastFind = rank[i] + left;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    private static class MergeSortTask extends Thread {
        private long left;
        private long right;
        private  Long[] result;

        public MergeSortTask(long left, long right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.result = new Long[(int) (right-left)];
            for(int i= 0;i<(right-left);i++){
                this.result[i]=arr[(int) (i+left)];
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mergeSort(this.result, (int) (right-left));
        }

    }

    public static void mergeSort(Long[] a, int n) {
        if(n<2)
            return;
        int mid = n / 2;
        Long[] l = new Long[mid];
        Long[] r = new Long[n - mid];

        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            l[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
            r[i - mid] = a[i];
        }
        mergeSort(l, mid);
        mergeSort(r, n - mid);

        merge(a, l, r, mid, n - mid);
    }

    public static void  merge(Long[] a, Long[] l, Long[] r, int left, int right) {
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < left && j < right) {
            if (l[i] <= r[j]) {
                a[k++] = l[i++];
            }
            else {
                a[k++] = r[j++];
            }
        }
        while (i < left) {
            a[k++] = l[i++];
        }
        while (j < right) {
            a[k++] = r[j++];
        }
    }

    static public Long[] getArray(int beginning, int length) {
        Long[] num = new Long[length];
        num[0] = (long) beginning;
        Random r = new Random(1);
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            int tmp = r.nextInt(10);
            if (tmp < 7 ) num[i] = num[i - 1];
            else num[i] = num[i - 1] + r.nextInt(4);
        }
        Long[] randomPosition=new Long[length];
        Arrays.fill(randomPosition,Long.MIN_VALUE);
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            int tmp=0;
            while(randomPosition[tmp]!=Long.MIN_VALUE){ tmp = r.nextInt(length);}
            randomPosition[tmp]=num[i];
        }
        return randomPosition;
    }
    static public void check(Long[] result){
        boolean check = true;
        if(result.length!=checking.length){
            System.out.println("length do mot match");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < checking.length; i++) {
            if (!result[i].equals(checking[i])) {
                check = false;
                System.out.println(i + " " + result[i] + " " + checking[i]);
            }
        }
        if (check)
            System.out.println("checked");
        else
            System.out.println("unchecked");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MergeSortTask[] tasks = new MergeSortTask[pnum];

        arr=getArray(beginning,size);

        checking = new Long[size];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, checking, 0, size);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Arrays.parallelSort(checking);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Build in parallel sort cost "+(end-start)+" Millis.");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int left=0;
        int right=size/pnum;
        int last=size%pnum;
        for (int i = 0; i < pnum; i++) {
            if (last > 0) {
                right++;
                last--;
            }
            tasks[i] = new MergeSortTask(left, right);
            left = right;
            right += size / pnum;
            tasks[i].start();
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < pnum; i++) {
                tasks[i].join();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        }

        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("distribute into "+pnum+" sub tasks and get "+pnum+" sorted array cost "+(end-start)+" Millis.");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0;i<pnum;i++){
            que.offer(tasks[i].result);
        }
        while(que.size()>1){
            a=que.poll();
            b=que.poll();
            int lengthA=a.length, lengthB=b.length;
            result=new Long[lengthA+lengthB];
            Arrays.fill(result, Long.MIN_VALUE);
            int size=lengthA+lengthB;
            MergeTask[] mergeTasks = new MergeTask[pnum];
            right = size / pnum;
            last = size % pnum;
            int aleft = lengthA, bleft = lengthB;
            for (int i = 0; i < pnum; i++) {
                if (last > 0) {
                    right++;
                    last--;
                }
                int[] classes = new int[right];
                int[] ranks = new int[right];
                if (aleft >= right) {
                    Arrays.fill(classes, 0);
                    for (int j = 0; j < right; j++) {
                        ranks[j] = lengthA - aleft;
                        aleft--;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (aleft == 0) {
                        Arrays.fill(classes, 1);
                        for (int j = 0; j < right; j++) {
                            ranks[j] = lengthB - bleft;
                            bleft--;
                        }
                    } else {
                        int tmp = aleft;
                        for (int j = 0; j < tmp; j++) {
                            classes[j] = 0;
                            ranks[j] = lengthA - aleft;
                            aleft--;
                        }
                        for (int j = tmp; j < right; j++) {
                            classes[j] = 1;
                            ranks[j] = lengthB - bleft;
                            bleft--;
                        }
                    }
                }
                mergeTasks[i] = new MergeTask(classes, ranks);
                right = size / pnum;
                mergeTasks[i].start();
            }

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < pnum; i++) {
                    mergeTasks[i].join();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error " + e);
            }
            que.offer(result);

        }

        result=que.peek();

        end=System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("finish parallel merge in "+(end-start)+" Millis");

        check(result);
    }
}
```

And here is the question. I have a checking function, which I first use a built-in parallel sort function to get the ground truth and check whether the sorted array I got is right. Output the different values. As I assigned the seed, so the input should always be the same. But sometimes my own merging works, sometimes it does not. Moreover, when is does not work, the output result is also different.

85679 -9223372036854775808 38679

or
50110 -9223372036854775808 22694

etc.

And I do not know why. Is it about the multiple threads I used?
Thanks a lot

Comment: "I think there are not any bugs on it" but can you guarantee it?

Comment: Yes, I can guarantee it.

Comment: I like your moxy, but if I remember my half-assed CS courses correctly, you can't prove that there is no bug in a piece of code. It's called the Faulting Problem.

Comment: That is not the main point. For the first MergeSortTask, I can compare it with the ground truth, and I have done it on my own computer but did not include it due to decreasing the complexity of the code. And I have tried many times and the problem is not on that part. That is why I said it has no bug.

Comment: `Arrays.parallelSort()` is at least not documented to be stable, do you know if it is?